# Google Maps API v3, how to change marker icon when clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How can I change a marker icon when a marker is clicked (on a click event) and return it back to a normal icon when another marker is clicked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, so there may be a typos or bugs, but it should give you the idea.

First, define a callback to set all markers to the normal icon (to reset any previously clicked markers) and set the current clicked marker's icon to the selected icon:

```
var markerCallback = function() {
    for (var i=0; i<arrayOfMarkers.length; i++) {
        arrayOfMarkers[i].setIcon(normalIcon);
    }
    this.setIcon(selectedIcon);
 }
```

Then, assign the callback to the click event on each marker like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', markerCallback);
```

There are certainly some code improvements that could be made. For example, you might not want `normalIcon`, `selectedIcon`, and `arrayOfMarkers` to be global variables the way the code above assumes they are.  And if you have a lot of markers, you probably want to instead keep track of the previously selected marker rather than having a `for` loop reset the icon on every one of them.

But like I said, this should give you the idea.

Comment: Would be a lot easier to simply assign the currently selected marker to a global variable instead of running through all the markers each time :)

Comment: @Kasper: Yes, you are correct, that would be better!  (In my defense, I did mention that issue: "And if you have a lot of markers, you probably want to instead keep track of the previous selected marker rather than having a `for` loop reset the icon on every one of them.")

Comment: I am indeed sorry, I totally missed that part. Only focused on the code example :D

Comment: Oh, no need to apologize.  You highlighted an important thing that was kind of buried in my text and therefore easy to miss.  The addition of your comment improved the answer.  Cheers!

Answer (score 17):

Just in any case anyone wants to see an example of keeping track of the previous marker in a global variable like Kasper mentioned, here is what I did:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {

        if (selectedMarker) {
            selectedMarker.setIcon(normalIcon);
        }
        marker.setIcon(selectedIcon);
        selectedMarker = marker;
    });
```

(after setting selectedMarker as a global variable)

Comment: needed some changes for my case but the idea is super clean man, thanks